# How to limit a spider crawler to stop after a number of downloads have been reached in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to go to a website that has a list of files and download each item. The problem is that the daily download is limited (authentication system), so my spider needs to stop when several items are downloaded and he will not be able to download any files from there.

This is what I tried:
settings.py

```py
CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT = 10
CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 50
```

It does not work because scrapy is async for nature and is not smart enough to consider dropped items.
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

```py
class DownloadProductVersionPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    count = 0

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None, item=None):
        self.count+=1

        if self.count > 10:
            raise CloseSpider()
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        fileName = f"{adapter['providerId']}/{adapter['product']['id']}/{adapter['product']['id']}-v{adapter['productVersion']['version']}.zip"
        return fileName
```

Using a pipeline for downloads also does not work because the pipeline is executed for EACH item and does not store values between executions.

Comment: I don't have a scrapy project with file downloading handy to test, but I'm thinking you should be able to check the spider's `.stats` and raise a `CloseSpider` if  `file_status_count/downloaded` > 50? (possibly in a `ShutdownPipeline` which has a higher priority than `DownloadProductVersionPipeline` - and that'd make it easier to configure and remove if it turns out no longer needed without requiring changes to your pipeline)

Comment: nice catch! I am trying to look where I get the property "file_status_count/downloaded". Any tips? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/stats.html#DownloaderStats

Comment: Not risking an answer as I can't check but basically I _think_ you want something like https://gist.github.com/joncle/244f982561584763eee65e0e35d878aa

Comment: nice! it works! I write the answer

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

settings.py

```py
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'project.middlewares.ProjectDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
}
```

middlewares.py

```py
class ProjectDownloaderMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if (spider.crawler.stats.get_value('file_status_count/downloaded') is not None and spider.crawler.stats.get_value('file_status_count/downloaded') >= 10):
            raise CloseSpider(
                'More than 10 items were downloaded from the provider and the spider was suspended to avoid banning')
        return response
```

I decided to use the middleware instead of the pipeline because I believe it is more semantic.

Credits: Jon Clements♦

Comment: Cool - yup - makes more sense in the middleware for your case. Glad I could give you a pointer vaguely in the right direction :p